# Ruby on Rails 4 - sort records in .each and create records

Tags: loops, ruby-on-rails-4, each

In my application, I have 2 models `Post` & `PostTexts`.

Each `Post` has  `language`, `position`, `title` & `description`.

*Positions are: Title & Description*.

*Short about my application to get a better understanding*. User comes in and selects `languages` & texts that they want and will get a result of different post texts that they can use.

*For instance user selects:*

- **Title 1** => position: Title
- **Title 2** => position: Title
- **Description 1** => position: Description

Languages: **English, Spanish**

Currently I'm *creating* the texts by:

```
@languages = params[:languages].split(',')
@post_texts = params[:post_texts].split(',')
@post_texts.split(',').each do |id|
  @languages.split(',').each do |language|
    post_text = PostText.where(post_text_id: id)
    @titles = post_text.where(placement: 'title')
    @descriptions = banner_text.where(placement: 'description')
  end
end

@titles.each do |title|
  @descriptions.each do |description|
    Post.create(
        title: title.body,
        description: description.body,
        language: 'language here',
    )
  end
end
```

This works fine if I only select 1 language and result would be as:

```
Title 1 + Description 1
Title 2 + Description 1
```

But when I select several languages, *texts* mixes up and Spanish texts mixes up with english and vice versa.

What I want to achieve is when several languages has been selected, only English texts go with English and Spanish texts go with Spanish etc.

so result would be as:

```
English Title 1 + English Description 1
English Title 2 + English Description 1
Spanish Title 1 + Spanish Description 1
Spanish Title 2 + Spanish Description 1
```

Current result is *something* as below:

```
English Title 1 + English Description 1
English Title 1 + Spanish Description 1
Spanish Title 2 + Spanish Description 1
Spanish Title 2 + English Description 1
```

*ps: Sorry if the description is not that good*

I have also tested with 2 different ways but results are the same:

## 1

```
@languages = params[:languages].split(',')
@post_texts = params[:post_texts].split(',')
@post_texts.split(',').each do |id|
  post_text = PostText.where(post_text_id: id)
  @titles = post_text.where(placement: 'title')
  @descriptions = banner_text.where(placement: 'description')
end

@languages.split(',').sort { |a,b| a.lang <=> b.lang }.each do |lang|
  @bodies  = @titles.where(language: lang)
  @ctas    = @descriptions.where(language: lang)
end

@titles.each do |title|
  @descriptions.each do |description|
    Post.create(
        title: title.body,
        description: description.body,
        language: 'language here',
    )
  end
end
```

## 2

```
@languages = params[:languages].split(',')
@post_texts = params[:post_texts].split(',')
@post_texts.split(',').each do |id|
  post_text = PostText.where(post_text_id: id)
  @titles = post_text.where(placement: 'title')
  @descriptions = banner_text.where(placement: 'description')
end

@languages.split(',').map { |lang|
  @bodies  = @titles.where(language: lang)
  @ctas    = @descriptions.where(language: lang)
end

@titles.each do |title|
  @descriptions.each do |description|
    Post.create(
        title: title.body,
        description: description.body,
        language: 'language here',
    )
  end
end
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the results you want, you need to specify it in your last `loop`, where you create your records, by doing `.where(field: loop.value)`, which in your case would be `where(language: title.language)` and the same with your `post_text` variable.

## Shange

```
post_text = PostText.where(post_text_id: id)
```

## To:

```
post_text = PostText.where(post_text_id: id).where(language: lang)
```

The code would be as below:

```
@languages = params[:languages].split(',')
@post_texts = params[:post_texts].split(',')
@post_texts.split(',').each do |id|
  @languages.split(',').each do |lang|
    post_text = PostText.where(post_text_id: id).where(language: lang)
    @titles = post_text.where(placement: 'title')
    @descriptions = banner_text.where(placement: 'description')
  end
end

@titles.each do |title|
  @descriptions.where(language: title.language).each do |description|
    Post.create(
        title: title.body,
        description: description.body,
        language: 'language here',
    )
  end
end
```

The main part that has been changed is `@descriptions.each do |description|`, by changing it to `@descriptions.each do |description|`